# SSL auto-detection for single directory (using X-Forwarded-Proto) not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, url-rewriting

I'm sure this is something stupid, and I've just been looking at this too long.

I'm running Apache 2.4.10

I want a single directory to force the user into HTTPS. Outside of that directory, I want the user to be bounced back to standard HTTP (unless they are loading the support files for an HTTPS page, eg. images, css)

This is behind a load balancer, and the load balancer is handling the HTTPS, so I'm relying on the X-Forwarded-Proto header as all the requests come into the nodes with the same protocol and port otherwise. I've doublechecked, and the header IS being populated by the LB for both HTTP and HTTPS transactions.

This is what I have in my config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/secureDir/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secureDir/(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(gif|jpg|png|swf|css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This is what I'm wanting, and what I THINK should be happening.
If the request came in over HTTP AND the request is for a resource in "/secureDir/" - the request will be bounced to HTTPS (at the same REQUEST_URI).
If the request came in over HTTPS and the request is NOT inside "/secureDir/" it will be bounced to HTTP (unless it is just a request for gif|jpg|etc).

This should seamlessly move a user back and forth between HTTPS and HTTP if they move in and out of the secureDir directory ... BUT it is not.

If I hit the secureDir directory, it is not automatically putting me in HTTPS. If I manually request as HTTPS it will put the request through. If I move out of the secureDir directory, it will automatically put me back into HTTP. So, it seems the 2nd set of Rewrite conditions are catching, but not the first.

I've also tried alternating the conditions to look for the inverse (!http, !https - but I still seem to only get one catch)

Any insight as to what I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. There was an unterminated rewrite a few lines prior, so it was appending those conditions to the first set of conditions in this group.

For anyone else who may be trying to do a similar thing - the only other thing I changed was to change the "http" match for X-Forwarded-Proto to "^http$" to make sure it wasn't greedy (as I got some 'infinite redirect' conditions if I didn't)